# What can happen to your motorcycle when you don't maintain or use it for a period of time? When do things start to go wrong?

Tags: motorcycle

Besides battery drainage, what happens to your bike when you keep it unused for a period?

What things can go wrong and what are their causes and when do they start to appear on your bike?

Would a low mileage fairly new bike face the same problems?

I've been told that stuff like engine oils and fluids don't go bad that fast but I've also noticed problems driving old and new bikes after a week or more like the engine doesn't feel that smooth, noises from the exhaust and engine, smoke etc but I don't know what they mean.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is very subjective. It really depends on so many factors (temperatures, age of bike, where you live, etc). There is no single answer which will provide you what you're looking for. As it stands, your question is too broad to be answered, then opinions will abound as well. Consider reducing the scope of your question to make it easier to answer. You can also ask as many questions as you like, so don't be afraid.

Comment: I think we could restate this as a question about the kind of things that go wrong and the factors that cause/accelerate them.

Comment: I feel like this is a fine question, and is not subjective at all. In involves the evolving properties of various elements in response to a constrained number of variables over time. It involves a large response, but not a boundless one. Main answers: gas volatiles evaporate, leaving sticky residues, especially when ethanol is present; oil accidifies; some metals rust (engine is one problem, electrical components and connectors are another); animals can attack electrical parts as well, or build nests in the airbox...

Comment: In addition to what was previously posted, the hydraulic system will absorb moisture from the air and the master cylinders and calipers may corrode and seize.